# : ORA-01722: invalid number error in JSTL query

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, servlets, jstl

guys i am working on web application in jsp and servlets and oracle SQL developer .. in myjsp.jsp i have a list

```
List<String> sexList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("sexList"); %>
```

and put it in cumbo box in JSTL tag like this

```
       <select name="sex">
          <c:forEach items="${sexList}" var="sex">
   <option value="${sex}">${sex}</option>
    </c:forEach>
      </select>
```

and i wrote a query like

```
<sql:query dataSource="${dbcon}" var="result">
 select firstname,lastname from members where sex = ?
 <sql:param value="${sex}"></sql:param>
```

and the sex in my database is number(0,1) .. so any help to avoid the error ??

Comment: To avoid which error?

Comment: @CloudyMarble this one ": ORA-01722: invalid number"

Comment: what does `sexlist` consists of ?

Comment: @SanKrish male and female

Comment: So you need to translate 'male' and 'female' to 0 and 1?

Comment: @AlexPoole how can i do that ?

Comment: something like: if sex == male the compare with 1 in your sql otherwise with 0